# HTML/CSS: How to create a box for the footer?

Tags: html, css, web

I tried doing the following on my header and it works:

```
h1{
    background-color: lightgrey;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 25px;
    border: 25px solid navy;
    margin: 25px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

footer{
    background-color: lightgrey;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 25px;
    border: 25px solid navy;
    margin: 25px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

However when I change the h1 to footer it only displays the text, but no box.
What should I do instead?

My html:

```
<body>

<h1> <center>HEADER</center> </h1>

<div class="body">
    blablabla
</div>

<footer>
    FOOTER
</footer>

</body>
```

edit: ok, now it has the box displayed. However, the box is very small compare to my header. How can I make them the same size?

Comment: What do you mean by changing `the h1 to footer`?

Comment: Can you show the html?

Comment: When you change your `<h1>` to a `<footer>`, do you change the css from `h1{` to `footer{` ??

Comment: and where is your footer css?

Comment: Are you using a browser that supports HTML5 and a DTD that invokes standards mode?

Comment: Regarding your edit: to make them the same size, set the same `font-size`: http://jsfiddle.net/woz93kph/1/

Comment: he's confusing header with HEADING, hence all the comments. to the OP: Try reading about HEADING ELEMENTS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements and HEADER TAGS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header . They have different properties, hence your different display issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<h1>` and `<footer>` tags have different standard styling.

Change your footer to this to make them look the same:

```
footer{
    background-color: lightgrey;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 25px;
    border: 25px solid navy;
    margin: 25px;
    border-radius: 15px;

    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```